# Hibernate with spring configuration.

Tags: spring, hibernate

I have trying to configure hibernate with spring and I am using entityManager.

After I have done configuration, I have the next error.

**The error:**

```
    Mar 27, 2014 12:53:28 PM com.google.apphosting.utils.jetty.JettyLogger warn WARNING: Nested in org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'entityManagerFactory' defined in ServletContext resource [/WEB-INF/applicationContext.xml]: Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: javax.persistence.Table.indexes()[Ljavax/persistence/Index;: java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: javax.persistence.Table.indexes()[Ljavax/persistence/Index; at org.hibernate.cfg.annotations.EntityBinder.processComplementaryTableDefinitions(EntityBinder.java:936) at org.hibernate.cfg.AnnotationBinder.bindClass(AnnotationBinder.java:781) at org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration$MetadataSourceQueue.processAnnotatedClassesQueue(Configuration.java:3762) at org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration$MetadataSourceQueue.processMetadata(Configuration.java:3716) at org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration.secondPassCompile(Configuration.java:1410) at org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration.buildSessionFactory(Configuration.java:1844) at org.hibernate.jpa.boot.internal.EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl$4.perform(EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.java:850) at org.hibernate.jpa.boot.internal.EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl$4.perform(EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.java:843) at org.hibernate.boot.registry.classloading.internal.ClassLoaderServiceImpl.withTccl(ClassLoaderServiceImpl.java:399) at org.hibernate.jpa.boot.internal.EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.build(EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.java:842) at org.hibernate.jpa.HibernatePersistenceProvider.createContainerEntityManagerFactory(HibernatePersistenceProvider.java:150) at org.hibernate.ejb.HibernatePersistence.createContainerEntityManagerFactory(HibernatePersistence.java:67) at org.springframework.orm.jpa.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean.createNativeEntityManagerFactory(LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean.java:288) at org.springframework.orm.jpa.AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.afterPropertiesSet(AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.java:310) at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory$6.run(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1531) at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method) at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.invokeInitMethods(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1529) at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1479) at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:521) at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:458) at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:295) at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:223) at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:292) at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:194) at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.getBean(AbstractApplicationContext.java:1117) at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:922) at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:479) at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader.configureAndRefreshWebApplicationContext(ContextLoader.java:389) at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader.initWebApplicationContext(ContextLoader.java:294) at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener.contextInitialized(ContextLoaderListener.java:112) at org.mortbay.jetty.handler.ContextHandler.startContext(ContextHandler.java:548) at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.Context.startContext(Context.java:136) at org.mortbay.jetty.webapp.WebAppContext.startContext(WebAppContext.java:1250) at org.mortbay.jetty.handler.ContextHandler.doStart(ContextHandler.java:517) at org.mortbay.jetty.webapp.WebAppContext.doStart(WebAppContext.java:467) at org.mortbay.component.AbstractLifeCycle.start(AbstractLifeCycle.java:50) at org.mortbay.jetty.handler.HandlerWrapper.doStart(HandlerWrapper.java:130) at org.mortbay.component.AbstractLifeCycle.start(AbstractLifeCycle.java:50) at org.mortbay.jetty.handler.HandlerWrapper.doStart(HandlerWrapper.java:130) at org.mortbay.jetty.Server.doStart(Server.java:224) at org.mortbay.component.AbstractLifeCycle.start(AbstractLifeCycle.java:50) at com.google.appengine.tools.development.JettyContainerService.startContainer(JettyContainerService.java:249) at com.google.appengine.tools.development.AbstractContainerService.startup(AbstractContainerService.java:306) at com.google.appengine.tools.development.AutomaticInstanceHolder.startUp(AutomaticInstanceHolder.java:26) at com.google.appengine.tools.development.AbstractModule.startup(AbstractModule.java:79) at com.google.appengine.tools.development.Modules.startup(Modules.java:88) at com.google.appengine.tools.development.DevAppServerImpl.start(DevAppServerImpl.java:241) at com.google.appengine.tools.development.gwt.AppEngineLauncher.start(AppEngineLauncher.java:97) at com.google.gwt.dev.DevMode.doStartUpServer(DevMode.java:509) at com.google.gwt.dev.DevModeBase.startUp(DevModeBase.java:1093) at com.google.gwt.dev.DevModeBase.run(DevModeBase.java:836) at com.google.gwt.dev.DevMode.main(DevMode.java:311)
------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

Comment: this is a very long line of exception :D

Answer (score 0):

`[/WEB-INF/applicationContext.xml]: Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: javax.persistence.Table.indexes()[Ljavax/persistence/Index;`

This can be a nightmare to debug. I've found that this exception generally means I've compiled with one version of a jar and executed with another version. Try to look at all the version within your war/ear and also check what you're compiling with to make sure they're all the same.